# Excel - Find if a product changed price

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

How can I find if a product changed it's price in excel? For example:

Yesterday's prices:

```
Potatoes 5,50
Tomatoes 7.40
Apples 5.60
Cucumber 4.30
```

Today's prices:

```
Potatoes 5,50
Tomatoes 5.20
Apples 5.50
Cucumber 4.30
```

Tomatoes and apples changed their price. How is it possible to highlight those changes based on "A" column product description?

Comment: Are the descriptions in column A and the prices in column B? Could there be lots of duplicates and you want all of them highlighting  where the price has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can try.  I also attached some pics for your reference.

`Columns A and B` are for yesterday's prices, `columns C and D` are for today's prices, and `column E` is to see the price changes (you don't need `column E` but I just want to show you so you know what is happening).  Also, the formula for `column E` is `=INDEX($A$3:$B$7,MATCH($C3,$A$3:$A$7,0),2)-$D3`.

[image]

- To highlight whichever product had price changed.  We will use `Conditional Formatting` which is under `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...`.  Under `cell D3`, you enter the same formula like in `cell E3` which is `=INDEX($A$3:$B$7,MATCH($C3,$A$3:$A$7,0),2)-$D3`.  Pick the color you want as the pic sample below.

  [image]
- Then applies to `=$D$3:$D$6` just like the pic shows below.

  [image]

This should work for you.  Try and let me know.

Comment: Unfortenately I cant because of my reputation. When I'll go over 15, I will do it. Thanks!

Comment: That is totally fine and I understand that is the rule here.  But thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will return `TRUE` if an item in the list has changed price:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,A1,$B$1:$B$8,"<>"&B1)>0
```

[image]

Enter it in `C1` (in this example) and drag down

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional formatting on another column. E.g. have a column of Yesterday-Today and highlight if <> 0.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, use the formula

```
=IF((AND(A1=C1,B1<>D1)),"yes","no")
```

where A1, C1 have fruite and B1, D1 have prices.
Below is the result obtained.

```
Potatoes    5,50    Potatoes    5,50    no
Tomatoes    7.4     Tomatoes    5.2     yes
Apples      5.6     Apples      5.5     yes
Cucumber    4.3     Cucumber    4.3     no
```

Then you can filter/highlight based on whether it is a yes/no.

Comment: This is only possible per row. Sometimes supplier adds new products between the yesterday's so we need a formula that works vertically.

Can we highlight duplicates based only on column "A"?